# Convert List of List to Pandas Dataframe with a set number in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

I have a list of list in Python:

```
list_1 = [123, 1344, 678, 1455, 900, 1899, 567]
list_2 = [1677, 2334]
list_3 = [2010, 1234]
lst = []
lst.append(list_1)
lst.append(list_2)
lst.append(list_3)
print(lst)
```

The output is:

```
[[123, 1344, 678, 1455, 900, 1899, 567], [1677, 2334], [2010, 1234]]
```

Now I am trying to convert it into a dataframe where the output shows which set each of the list items belongs to. Like the first set is in Set 1, then Set 2, and so on...

Desired Dataframe output:

| Number | Set |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 |
| 1344 | 1 |
| 678 | 1 |
| 1455 | 1 |
| 900 | 1 |
| 1899 | 1 |
| 567 | 1 |
| 1677 | 2 |
| 2334 | 2 |
| 2010 | 3 |
| 1234 | 3 |

This is what I had tried, but I don't understand the issue:

```
a = len(lst)     
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Number','Set'])
        for i in lst:
           for j in range(a):
             df2= pd.DataFrame({'Number':i})
             df2['Set']=j+1
             pd.concat([df2,df3],ignore_index = True)
             print(df2)
             break
```

Comment: @Julien I mentioned the code I tried.

Comment: Now just make it a [mre] please.

Comment: Is it the right way to post? @Julien

Comment: No. Follow the instructions in [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple list comprehension with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
lst = [[123, 1344, 678, 1455, 900, 1899, 567], [1677, 2334], [2010, 1234]]

df = pd.DataFrame([[x, i] for i, l in enumerate(lst, start=1) for x in l],
                  columns=['Number', 'Set'])
```

Output:

```
    Number  Set
0      123    1
1     1344    1
2      678    1
3     1455    1
4      900    1
5     1899    1
6      567    1
7     1677    2
8     2334    2
9     2010    3
10    1234    3
```

Or using [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) (less efficient):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(enumerate(lst, start=1), columns=['Set', 'Number']
                  ).explode('Number')
```

Output:

```
   Set Number
0    1    123
0    1   1344
0    1    678
0    1   1455
0    1    900
0    1   1899
0    1    567
1    2   1677
1    2   2334
2    3   2010
2    3   1234
```

If you really want to use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), don't use it in a loop as it has quadratic complexity (it will be very slow for large lists), just `concat` **once**:

```
df = pd.concat(map(pd.Series, lst), keys=range(1, len(lst)+1),
               names=['Set']).reset_index('Set', name='Number')
```

Output:

```
   Set  Number
0    1     123
1    1    1344
2    1     678
3    1    1455
4    1     900
5    1    1899
6    1     567
0    2    1677
1    2    2334
0    3    2010
1    3    1234
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
lst = [[123, 1344, 678, 1455, 900, 1899, 567], [1677, 2334], [2010, 1234]]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Number', 'Set'])
i = 1
for l in lst:
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['Number'])
    new_df['Set'] = i
    df = pd.concat([df,new_df], axis = 0)
    i = i + 1
df

  Number Set
0    123   1
1   1344   1
2    678   1
3   1455   1
4    900   1
5   1899   1
6    567   1
0   1677   2
1   2334   2
0   2010   3
1   1234   3
```

Comment: Using `concat` in a loop is definitely not a good pandas approach, for each new list in `lst` and `concat` operation, you'll have to recreate the full set of rows which has a quadratic complexity. A minima, collect in a list and use `concat` once, but here I think `concat` is not even needed.